# ROSJava compiling error

Tags: ros, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to compile rosjava on an Ubuntu 10.10 machine, but I have run across a error.

The error is:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.ros.internal.message.GenerateInterfaces.main(GenerateInterfaces.java:162)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':rosjava_messages:generateSources'.

> Command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java' finished with (non-zero) exit value 1.

The stacktrace is:

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':rosjava_messages:generateSources'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:68)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:34)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:34)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$2.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:200)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:172)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:198)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:111)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:83)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:32)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:247)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.executeTask(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:192)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.doExecute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:177)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:83)
  at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:36)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$1.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:111)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:126)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:109)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:103)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
  at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:155)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:110)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:78)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:45)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Build.run(Build.java:67)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Build.run(Build.java:63)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:45)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$4.call(ForwardClientInput.java:116)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$4.call(ForwardClientInput.java:114)
  at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:114)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:61)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:36)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleClientDisconnectBeforeSendingCommand.execute(HandleClientDisconnectBeforeSendingCommand.java:21)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StopConnectionAfterExecution.execute(StopConnectionAfterExecution.java:27)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon$1$1.run(Daemon.java:123)
  at org.gradle.messaging.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
  Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java' finished with (non-zero) exit value 1.
  at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:338)
  at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:34)
  at org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.exec(JavaExec.java:50)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:196)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:102)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:99)
  at org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
  at org.gradle.util.ReflectionUtil.invoke(ReflectionUtil.groovy:23)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$4.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:150)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$4.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:145)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:477)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:466)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:60)
  ... 76 more

BUILD FAILED

Any help will be appreciative

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40763/rosjava-compiling-error/) by [James 412](https://answers.ros.org/users/2989/james-412/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2012-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is not defined. Be sure to follow the [instructions for installing rosjava](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/installing.html). And be sure to:

```
$ cd my_ros_workspace
$ source setup.bash
```

It's best to add the `source setup.bash` line to your `bash.rc`.

I've also filed an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=135) to provide a more informative error message.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0